# Google Glass: how to get a Card to refresh after setting text

Tags: refresh, google-glass, google-gdk

How can I go about refreshing a `Card` after setting the footnote for it?

Basically, there is a footnote already set for the `Card` when it is initially created:

```
    private void createCards() {
    mCards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    Card card;
    String[] step;

    for (int i = 0; i < steps.size(); i++) {
        step = steps.get(i);
        card = new Card(this);
        card.setText(step[1]);
        card.setFootnote("Result:");
        mCards.add(card);
    }
}
```

But when I click the menu option Yes or No for that `Card`, I set the footnote again to show "Result: YES" or "Result: No":

```
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 1:
            resultYesNo = true;
            currentCard.setFootnote("Result: YES");
            return true;
        case 2:
            resultYesNo = false;
            currentCard.setFootnote("Result: NO");
            return true;
```

**And it does change the footnote, but I have to scroll three cards left or right then go back to the `Card` to see the change happen.**

I want it the `Card` to refresh right away after setting the footnote the 2nd time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update a card, after setting the new footnote, you have to notify the cardScrollAdapter:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 1:
        resultYesNo = true;
        currentCard.setFootnote("Result: YES");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //your cardScrollAdapter
        return true;
    case 2:
        resultYesNo = false;
        currentCard.setFootnote("Result: NO");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //your cardScrollAdapter
        return true;
}
```

Now, the cards should update.